# SQLite JDBC and SQLite version

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I just downloaded the JDBC driver

> sqlite-jdbc4-3.8.2-SNAPSHOT.jar

from

https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads

After that I included it into my eclipse project via

> Configure Build Path

And afterwards I ran this code:

```
public class SQLiteINPUT
    {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
      {
          newDB();
      }

        public static void  newDB () throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{


        try{                

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:newDB.db");                                       
            con.close();    

        }catch(Exception ed) {
            System.out.println("Error --> " + ed);
          }
        }}
```

Which successfully creates a new database-file called

> newDB.db

But if I open this file with Firefox SQLite Manager and run this code:

```
SELECT sqlite_version() AS 'SQLite Version';
```

It returns:

> SQLite Version - 3.7.17

And ***not 3.8.2*** as the JDBC driver says. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: `sqlite_version()` returns the version of the library that you are executing the query in. So you are asking for the version of the SQLite version used by Firefox SQLite Manager.

Comment: Ah okay. So the database file itselfs do not have any version? Just the "query library" of the JDBC and SQLite Manager?

Comment: I don't know sqlite well enough to know if there is a way to find the database file version.